# Need first instance only when joining two tables using data.table's :=

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I have a policyData which is my very huge data set (millions of rows) and I wish to add some info to it with a mapping table (tens of thousands of rows).

Sample:

```
policyData <- data.table(plan=c("c","b","b","d"),v=c(8,7,5,6),foo=c(4,2,8,3))
mapping <- data.table(plan=c("b","b","a","a","c","c"),a=c(1,2,4,5,7,8),b=c(9,8,6,5,3,2))
```

policyData:

```
   plan v foo
1:    c 8   4
2:    b 7   2
3:    b 5   8
4:    d 6   3
```

mapping:

```
   plan a b
1:    b 1 9
2:    b 2 8
3:    a 4 6
4:    a 5 5
5:    c 7 3
6:    c 8 2
```

Problem is that the mapping has multiple instances and I wish to get the first match only. And I need to join the two using memory efficient way using `:=`.

The desired output is:

```
   plan v foo  a  b
1:    c 8   4  7  3
2:    b 7   2  1  9
3:    b 5   8  1  9
4:    d 6   3 NA NA
```

I have tried:

```
policyData[mapping, on="plan", `:=`(a=i.a, b=i.b)]
```

which gives the last instance in the mapping table:

```
   plan v foo  a  b
1:    c 8   4  8  2
2:    b 7   2  2  8
3:    b 5   8  2  8
4:    d 6   3 NA NA
```

I have also tried:

```
policyData[mapping, on="plan", `:=`(a=i.a, b=i.b), mult="first"]
```

which gives strange result (the second "b" can't match with the mapping):

```
   plan v foo  a  b
1:    c 8   4  8  2
2:    b 7   2  2  8
3:    b 5   8 NA NA
4:    d 6   3 NA NA
```

Any insight would be helpful. I've done lots of searches already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggesting another alternative:

```
policyData[, c("a", "b") := mapping[.SD, on="plan", .(a, b), mult="first"]]
```

sample data to match OP's dimensions:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nrDS <- 100e6
nrMap <- 90e3
policyData <- data.table(plan=sample(letters,nrDS,TRUE),v=rnorm(nrDS),foo=rnorm(nrDS))
mapping <- data.table(plan=sample(letters,nrMap,TRUE),a=rnorm(nrMap),b=rnorm(nrMap))
```

memory profiling:

```
library(bench)
mark(mtd1=policyData[mapping[mapping[, .I[1L], by = plan]$V1], on = .(plan), `:=` (a = i.a, b = i.b)],
    mtd2=policyData[, c("a", "b") := mapping[.SD, on="plan", .(a, b), mult="first"]],
    mtd3=policyData[unique(mapping, by="plan"), on=.(plan), `:=` (a=i.a, b=i.b)])
```

memory profiling output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result                       memory                  time    gc             
  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>                       <list>                  <list>  <list>         
1 mtd1          7.07s    7.07s    7.07s    7.07s     0.141    4.74GB     0     1      7.07s <data.table [90,000,000 x 5~ <Rprofmem [31,589 x 3]> <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x 3~
2 mtd2          6.73s    6.73s    6.73s    6.73s     0.149    5.03GB     1     1      6.73s <data.table [90,000,000 x 5~ <Rprofmem [20 x 3]>     <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x 3~
3 mtd3          7.68s    7.68s    7.68s    7.68s     0.130    3.35GB     1     1      7.68s <data.table [90,000,000 x 5~ <Rprofmem [23 x 3]>     <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x 3~
```

Hugh method is the most memory efficient while mtd2 is fastest. As with most things in life, you need to make a tradeoff.

Comment: Your benchmark does not vary the number of groups, so `mapping[, .SD[1L], by = plan]` is very small and fast to compute. I guess with more groups, your way should be faster and more memory efficient. Side note: I would use `.(x.a, x.b)` to disambiguate.

Comment: Ok, posted benchmark (timing, not mem) with different data here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44045151#44045151

Comment: thanks, @Frank. I think the dimensions are flipped in the chat. OP has millions of rows in policyData and tens of thousands in mapping. The fastest and most memory efficient will depend on the kind of data that OP has. Hopefully, he can provide us the stats, then we can have some fun. Should try out Hugh method as well.

Answer (score 5):

Just summarise `mapping` with `mapping[, .SD[1], by = plan]` and use that for joining:

```
policyData[mapping[, .SD[1], by = plan]
           , on = .(plan)
           , `:=` (a = i.a, b = i.b)]
```

which gives the desired output:

> ```
> > policyData
>    plan v foo  a  b
> 1:    c 8   4  7  3
> 2:    b 7   2  1  9
> 3:    b 5   8  1  9
> 4:    d 6   3 NA NA
> ```

Comment: or `policyData[unique(mapping, by = "plan"), on="plan", `:=`(a=i.a, b=i.b)][]`