# How to do a join and only select a specific row from a related Group?

Tags: r

I don't know how to exactly phrase this Question. I hope it gets clearer when I provide you with an example:

```
Match <- data.frame(PlayerID=c(1,2,2,3,3), Date = c("01.04.2012","05.04.2012","20.04.2012","23.04.2012","30.04.2012"))     
Playerrating <- data.frame(PlayerID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), Date= c("01.03.2012","02.04.2012","01.05.2012","01.03.2012","19.04.2012","25.04.2012"),Rating=c(64,71,55,59,73,81))

> Match
PlayerID         Date
1          01.04.2012
2          05.04.2012
2          20.04.2012
3          23.04.2012
3          30.04.2012

> Playerrating
PlayerID       Date   Rating
1          01.03.2012     64
1          02.04.2012     71
1          01.05.2012     55
2          01.03.2012     59
2          19.04.2012     73
2          25.04.2012     81
```

I want to assign to the Match table the right player rating from the Playerrating table, which ist the first rating for the specific player after the date specified in the Match table. In this case it should look like the following:

```
Match
PlayerID       Date   Rating
1         01.04.2012     71
2         05.04.2012     73
2         20.04.2012     81
3         23.04.2012     NA
3         30.04.2012     NA
```

Can anybode help me out with this problem?

(This is my first question here so please forgive me, if I have not phrased this very comprehensible)

Comment: Related: [*Need first instance only when joining two tables using data.table's :=*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52474989/2204410)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a join with `data.table`, using `roll=-Inf` to roll the next value back.

```
library( data.table )
```

First convert your data frames to data tables.

```
setDT(Match)
setDT(Playerrating)
```

Convert the dates to `Date` class so they'll be treated appropriately.

```
Match[ , Date := as.Date( Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y" ) ]
Playerrating[ , Date := as.Date( Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y" ) ]
```

Make sure the order is appropriate. This isn't necessary in your example, but is good practice.

```
setorder( Match, PlayerID, Date )
setorder( Playerrating, PlayerID, Date )
```

Do the join. Note the `roll=-Inf`. This is what brings the next available value into the join.

```
Playerrating[ Match, on = .( PlayerID, Date ), roll = -Inf ]
```

The result:

```
   PlayerID       Date Rating
1:        1 2012-04-01     71
2:        2 2012-04-05     73
3:        2 2012-04-20     81
4:        3 2012-04-23     NA
5:        3 2012-04-30     NA
```

Comment: Per Jaap's link, it's better to add a column to Match than to create a new table, imo. `Match[, v := Playerrating[ Match, on = .( PlayerID, Date ), roll = -Inf, x.Rating]]`

Comment: @Frank do you mean for efficiency? Isn't `.SD` effectively creating in-memory copies anyway?

Comment: Do you have a link for the syntax of this line of your code?:
Playerrating[ Match, on = .( PlayerID, Date ), roll = -Inf ]

Comment: @rosscova Nah, I just meant for simplicity. Why make a third table when the column fits naturally into one of the tables you already have? (There is also an argument for saving RAM by adding a column to an existing table vs creating a new one, but I rarely run into that problem myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
# load the package
library(data.table)

# convert the dataframe's to data.table's
# and convert the 'Date'-columns to actual Date-class
setDT(Match)[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")][]
setDT(Playerrating)[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")][]

# join option 1:
Match[, rating := Playerrating[.SD, on = .(PlayerID, Date > Date)
                               , mult = "first", x.Rating]]

# join option 2: (per @Frank's comment)
Match[, rating := Playerrating[.SD, on = .(PlayerID, Date)
                               , roll = -Inf, x.Rating]][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > Match
>    PlayerID       Date rating
> 1:        1 2012-04-01     71
> 2:        2 2012-04-05     73
> 3:        2 2012-04-20     81
> 4:        3 2012-04-23     NA
> 5:        3 2012-04-30     NA
> ```

---

A solution with base R:

```
m <- outer(Match$PlayerID, Playerrating$PlayerID, "==") & outer(Match$Date, Playerrating$Date, "<=")
Match$Rating <- Playerrating$Rating[max.col(m, "first") * NA^!rowSums(m)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > Match
>   PlayerID       Date Rating
> 1        1 2012-04-01     71
> 2        2 2012-04-05     73
> 3        2 2012-04-20     81
> 4        3 2012-04-23     NA
> 5        3 2012-04-30     NA
> ```

Comment: @HansGeber Thx, I've added a base R solution as well.

Comment: I tried to use your base R solution but I get the following error:----
Error in rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y))) : invalid 'times' argument
------
So it seems that both tables have to be of the same length, is there a solution to this?

Comment: @HansGeber Both tables don't have to be of the same length. In you example data they aren't either and that works. Could you update your question with an additional example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: you are right, give me some time and I will add a sample of my actual tables

Comment: so I think the problem is that m is getting too big, with only 10 obervations in the match table and 184,000 rows in the players table, m has over 4mb.
If i take 100 rows from the match table, m hast 70mb

Comment: so to make it clear, the problem only seems to arise, when I work with my full dataset which I can not post here, because it is too large, but the other solutions have worked for me, so thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(Match, Playerrating, by = "PlayerID") %>%
    mutate(d = as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(Date.y, "%d.%m.%Y"), as.Date(Date.x, "%d.%m.%Y")))) %>%
    group_by(PlayerID, Date.x) %>%
    filter(d > 0 | is.na(Date.y)) %>%
    filter(rank(d) == 1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-Date.y, Rating, -d)
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#  PlayerID Date.x     Rating
#     <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
#1        1 01.04.2012     71
#2        2 05.04.2012     73
#3        2 20.04.2012     81
#4        3 23.04.2012     NA
#5        3 30.04.2012     NA
```

Explanation: Do a left join of `Match` and `Playerrating` by `PlayerID`, calculate the time difference between all dates, group by `PlayerID` and dates from `Match`, select rows with dates in `Playerrating` after those from `Match` (or missing dates), and finally only keep those entries from `Playerrating` that are closest to dates from `Match`.